# Passing a callback to js via DOM elements dataset

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, dataset

I have a modular system that fetches some data from my server and returns it to the client via ajax, whereupon the client does stuff with that data.

In order to keep the code modular I want to introduce a callback variable, so I can designate a callback function that changes depending on the data requested. This would preferably be inserted into an element relevant to the function (ie, a button or input)

Right now I am storing the callback function name in the dom, as an elements `data-callback="functionName"` property, and then `eval()`ing that value to run the callback.

snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'click', function( evt ){
  var tgt = evt.target;
  
  if( tgt.id == "btn" ){
  
    var callback = tgt.dataset.callback;
    var callbackParam = tgt.dataset.callbackParam;
  
    eval( callback + "('" + callbackParam + "')" );
  }
});



function foo( str ){

  document.getElementById( "returnDisplay" ).innerText = str;
  
  window.setTimeout( function(){
    document.getElementById( "returnDisplay" ).innerText = '';
  }, 1000 );
  
}
```

```html
<div id=returnDisplay></div>
<button id=btn data-callback="foo" data-callback-param="bar">Click me</button>
```

I know eval is considered dangerous, is there another way I can pass a callback into javascript via the DOM?

Comment: Why not binding the event directly?

Comment: @Ele, habit I guess, I like to handle all my events on the dom so I only bind a single event and then check against the event target to action it. It means that when I am adding elements to the DOM I don't need to assign events to every element I create with javascript, rather I can rest assured the event will be picked up at the DOM root and filtered out accordingly. I made it up myself, is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need using setTimeout.

```
var callback = tgt.dataset.callback;
setTimeout(callback);
```

if you need pass some parameters, you can, see example

```
let fncName = 'alert'
let fncParam = 'hello'
setTimeout(`${fncName}("${fncParam}")`)
```

Comment: Any gotchas with using the `${}` notation? is that a jquery thing or is it straight js?

Comment: This is placeholders for template strings, https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

You can also go about it like this--I referenced [these MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) when creating:

```html
<div id=returnDisplay></div>
<button id="btn" data-callback-param="bar" data-callback-function="myFunc">Click me</button>
```

```
const log = document.getElementById('btn');

log.onclick = clickHandler;

function clickHandler(e) {
  const {callbackParam, callbackFunction} = e.target.dataset
  eval(`${callbackFunction}("${callbackParam}")`)
}
```

Comment: Well, that simply logs a string embedded in a data attribute, it doesn't call a function by the name passed in the data attribute, which is what I wanted

Comment: Got it ...I guess I would question why you're doing that at all? It's pretty dangerous to eval on strings as you mentioned, and it seems like you could still build your system in a modular way where each component (or whatever your organizational unit is) could have its own handler that it initializes. Regardless, I'll update my answer to reflect what you were looking for :)